# Combining a 9v Battery and Bench Power Supply to power Opamp and circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, batteries

G'day
I want to provide a few op-amps with +-9V. However I only have a single 9v battery. Is there any problem with dialling up 9v on my lab psu and combining them to get the +-9V?

I would use a voltage divider  but I think I might have trouble with the current load.

Comment: As Nils Pipenbrinck answer states, that will be fine. Note however that the issue with a voltage divider would not be with stability. It would be with handling a varying load current.

Comment: @HoustonFortney very true. My apologies I did mean the current load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine a PSU and a battery everything will be fine.

Just be careful if you combine two bench power supply units. They may have the negative output internally connected to earth. If they do, then you'll generate a short via the earth if you try to build a bipolar supply out of two unipolar units.

Comment: Thanks Nils. Yep very good point. easy way to damage your scope too :)